# How to check period id and last updated value then assign to variable?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, sybase

I have table where users will be able to get the periods for each record. There are four different periods for each record. Here is example of table `periods` with data:

```
profile_id    year_id       last_update_dt         period_id
1234564        2019      2017-06-13 15:11:34           2
1234565        2019      2017-04-14 09:54:29           3
1234566        2019      2018-02-01 14:44:10           4
1234567        2019      2017-07-12 08:51:14           5
345356         2020      2019-12-23 12:34:56           2
```

Here is example of `profile` table data:

```
rec_id    year_id    profile_id
7548763    2018       988753  
7548763    2019       746546
7548763    2020       765745
6983234    2020       345356
```

Current code is developed with back end language (in my case ColdFusion) and looks like this:

```
<cfquery name="qPeriods" datasource="testDB">
   SELECT p2.last_update_dt AS period2, p3.last_update_dt AS period3, p4.last_update_dt AS period4
   FROM profile pf
   LEFT JOIN periods p2 ON pf.profile_id = p2.profile_id AND pf.year_id = p2.year_id AND p2.period_id = 3     
   LEFT JOIN periods p3 ON pf.profile_id = p3.profile_id AND pf.year_id = p3.year_id AND p3.period_id = 4     
   LEFT JOIN periods p4 ON pf.profile_id = p4.profile_id AND pf.year_id = p4.year_id AND p4.period_id = 5
   WHERE pf.rec_id = 7548763 AND pf.year_id = 2019
</cfquery>

<cfset period = 2 />
<cfset period = len(trim(qPeriods.period2)) gte '1' ? '3' : period />
<cfset period = len(trim(qPeriods.period3)) gte '1' ? '4' : period />
<cfset period = len(trim(qPeriods.period4)) gte '1' ? '5' : period />
```

As you can see I used hard coded values in `cfquery` to get some data for testing purpose. The logic will set default value for period `2`. Then it will check and override previous value if criteria is met and set to previous value if it's not. I was wondering if this can be simplified and instead of joining each period use only one join. So I came up with this example:

```
DECLARE @period varchar(1)
SELECT
    @period = CASE WHEN ps.period_id = 3 AND LTRIM(RTRIM(ps.last_update_dt)) IS NOT NULL THEN '3' END,
    @period = CASE WHEN ps.period_id = 4 AND LTRIM(RTRIM(ps.last_update_dt)) IS NOT NULL THEN '4' END,
    @period = CASE WHEN ps.period_id = 5 AND LTRIM(RTRIM(ps.last_update_dt)) IS NOT NULL THEN '5' END,
    @period = CASE WHEN @period IS NULL THEN '2' END
FROM profile pf
    LEFT JOIN periods ps ON pf.profile_id = ps.profile_id AND ps.year_id = ps.year_id
WHERE pf.rec_id = 7548763 AND pf.year_id = 2019
```

For some reason code above was always giving `2` as a result. I'm not sure why that's happening. I looked over the code multiple times but still can;t find the reason why it's failing. If anyone see the issue with the code I created in SQL please let me know.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205109/discussion-on-question-by-espresso-coffee-how-to-check-period-id-and-last-update). If asked for more information, please edit the requested information into your question.

Comment: How is data inserted into `periods` that relates to `profile`? Currently, the example data doesn't match up to return a record. Take a look at your example data. If `rec_id` is a Primary Key, there can't be multiples of the same value, yet there are in the example. I'm a bit confused about your data. The example looks like `rec_id` and `year_id` together make up the Primary Key. But then the `profile_id` doesn't match the `periods` table. Can you please clarify your example?

Comment: @Shawn my bad, profile_id is primary key. I was looking over so many things and made a mistake. Sorry about that.

Comment: @espresso_coffee This question may need to be closed and asked again with clearer details. When a mod moves a discussion seeking to clarify the problem to chat, then the actual question needing to be asked has probably lost a lot of context that would be needed for the answers.

Comment: *I was looking over so many things and made a mistake.* Happens to all of us, but fixing the data sample would make it much easier for someone to answer the question. My guess - your last query is very close, but you don't need a @period variable. Order the matching records by the latest period first and return the top 1 date `SELECT TOP 1 p.period_id, p.last_update_dt FROM .... ORDER BY p.period_id DESC`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the below SQL:

```
DECLARE @Value INT
SET @Value = 5
SELECT @Value = CASE WHEN 1 = 2 THEN 123 END
SELECT @Value
```

If you run this you'll see that @Value turns out to be NULL, not 5.  This is because when the condition in the CASE statement is not met and it has no ELSE then it doesn't ignore setting the variable, it sets it to NULL.

If you take this and look at your code you will see that if the "@period = CASE WHEN ps.period_id = 5 ..." condition is not met then @period will be set to NULL, thus causing the next part "@period = CASE WHEN @period IS NULL" to pass the condition and then set it to 2.

Basically, you're expecting the value of @period to be what it was the last time it passed a condition in one of the CASE statements, when in reality it's setting it to NULL each time it fails.  To avoid this, try adding "ELSE @period" clauses to each CASE.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same result with SQL instead of using back end language?

Comment: I modified my post with a suggestion shortly after you responded .  Try adding "ELSE @period" in each CASE statement

Comment: What about just setting default value for `@value` to be equal to `2`. In that case if none of the case statements is met default value will be used.

Comment: The problem here is that if "@period = CASE WHEN ps.period_id = 3 ..." passes and sets the value of @period to be 3, then it will immediately set the value back to NULL when it processes "@period = CASE WHEN ps.period_id = 4 ..." because it will fail the condition and since there is no ELSE clause it defaults the value to NULL.  If you had "@period = CASE WHEN ps.period_id = 4 ... THEN '4' ELSE @period" then it will still be set to 3 if the condition fails.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the record with the smallest `period_id` for a given user, you could just sort and `top 1`:

```
select top 1 per.last_update
from profiles pro
inner join periods per 
    on pro.profile_id = per.profile_id 
    and pro.year_id = per.year_id
where 
    pro.year_id = 2019 
    and pro.rec_id = 7548763
order by per.period_id
```

Comment: How that will solve the problem? Have you tried running this code with example of the data I provided? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on an earlier comment made by @espresso_coffee:

"*We always want to return the highest period.*"

I take this to mean the objective is to return a single row with the `max(period_id)` for a given `profile_id/year_id` combo; if my understanding is correct then how about a simple `max()` query, eg:

```
select isnull(max(period_id),'2')
from   periods
where  rec_id  = 7548763
and    year_id = 2019
and    ltrim(rtrim(ps.last_update_dt)) is not NULL
```

'course, this assumes that a record in `profile` does exist; if it's possible for rows to exist in `periods` without a matching row in `profile`, we could add a join (or `exists()` sub-query) to verify the existence of a row in `profile`.

NOTE: I'm assuming Sybase ASE; if this is one of the other Sybase RDBMS products (eg, IQ, SQLAnywhere, Advantage) then we may need to switch out the `isnull()` for the corresponding function.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be setting the same parameter multiple times in a `select`.  Your last `select` is better written as:

```
SELECT @period = (CASE WHEN ps.period_id IN (3, 4, 5) AND 
                            LTRIM(RTRIM(ps.last_update_dt)) IS NOT NULL
                       THEN CAST(ps.period_id AS CHAR(1))
                       ELSE '2'
                  END)
```

Comment: I think in order for this solution to work query has to use `ORDER BY ps.period_id`. Otherwise this will not work as expected.